# Arduino for push notifications to phone

Tags: wifi, shields, ethernet

I'm interested in using an Arduino for a project for taking information and sending it through a phone application. I was wondering what the cheapest option there is for an arduino with internet capabilities. From what I see, a lot of articles list they use UNOs with shields for wifi/ethernet. After looking these up, I noticed that they can get a little pricey. Is there any alternative options I may be overlooking? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look into buying an ESP8266 WiFi module (cca. 7$) and add it to your existing Arduino. If you're not constrained with money that much I would then recommend look up Arduino Industrial 101, which comes with WiFi out of the box. You could then use MQTT protocol to send messages to a broker and your phone. There are alot of nice tutorials online on MQTT.

Comment: Also, the ESP8266 itself can be coded with the Arduino IDE/environment, and could replace an existing arduino. In general the ESP8266's have more RAM and flash storage than the UNO.

Comment: Is it possible to use any GPIO on ESP8266? It would be nice to hook the sensor directly onto ESP8266. For example DHT22.

Comment: The ESP8266 has several GPIO pins. https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/doc/reference.md#digital-io
Note that they are 3.3V, not 5V like the UNO.

Comment: Well then you can't get any cheaper than ESP8266 if your requirements are limited to a few GPIOs. Thank you for pointing that out @josecanuc.